# Button doesn't work inside the html form but it works outside

Tags: javascript, html, forms, summernote

Hi there I need some help with this html form!
I'm making a bulletin board using summernote
(https://summernote.org/examples/)

At first I made the button(save, edit) outside the form and it perfectly worked.

[Clicking edit button shows the editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7GFe.png)

[And the save button saves the change and hides the editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bojzf.png)

However as I moved it inside it wouldn't work.
Can't figure out why... Are the elements inside the form independent from the rest?

If not, what did I do wrong?
And what should I change to make two buttons exist inside the editor form?

Html that works :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
    <form class="edit-summit-form" method="post" action="      ">
            <div id="editor">

            </div>
    </form>
    <p>
        <!--<div id="summernote-result"></div>-->
    </p>
    <button id="edit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="edit()" type="button">Edit 1</button>
    <button id="save" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="save()" type="button">Save 2</button>
    <div class="click2edit">click2edit</div>
</div>
```

Html that doesn't work :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
    <form class="edit-summit-form" method="post" action="      ">
            <div id="editor">
              <button id="edit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="edit()" type="button">Edit 1</button>
              <button id="save" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="save()" type="button">Save 2</button>
              <div class="click2edit">click2edit</div>
            </div>
    </form>
    <p>
        <!--<div id="summernote-result"></div>-->
    </p>
</div>
```

Javascript :

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#summernote').summernote();
    });
    var edit = function() {
      $('.click2edit').summernote({focus: true});
    };
    var save = function() {
      var markup = $('.click2edit').summernote('code');
      $('.click2edit').summernote('destroy');
    };
```

Comment: Please define "_doesn't work_".

Comment: Create a snippet. Its hard to help when someone just writes code in plain text and says "_it doesnt work_"

Comment: I think the button fails to call the javascript function, when it 'works' the edit button successfully brings out the summernote editor as it is supposed to

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explained what "doesn't work", but I'm guessing your form is submitting and you don't want it to. Remove the onclick inline JS and have the event callback prevent form submission:

```
$('#save').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var markup = $('.click2edit').summernote('code');
    $('.click2edit').summernote('destroy');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!